# Using NESTED LOOP for a simple (difficult for me) output

Tags: c++, loops, nested

**I need to output

1 2 3

4 5 6

7 8 9

*using nested loop*...**

I tried this

```
for(int i=1;i<=6;i++)
 {
   cout<<endl;
   for(int j=1;j<=i and j<=3;++j)
   cout<<i++;
  }
```

The output was

123

567

Plzz.. help..

Comment: `for(int j=1;j<=i and j<=3;++j)` Did this compile? I find it hard to believe that beginners are aware of iso646.h

Comment: That's not C, but C++.

Comment: You are *almost* there.  See [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) by Eric Lippert.  The thing I notice is that you are incrementing `i` both in the `for` loop statement, and in the body of the for loop.  You only want one of those.

Comment: @Lundin:  His C++ compiler is seriously broken if it doesn't compile.

Comment: I didn't use anything like iso646.h i just used iostream

Comment: @MartinBonner Are you saying that it is possible to type `and` in C++ without including `iso646.h`?

Comment: @Lundin: Yes. `int main() { return true and true ? 0 : 1; }` is a complete and valid C++ program (which will return 0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find a solution like this to be much cleaner:

```
for( int i = 1; i < 10; ++i )
{
    std::cout << i;
    if( i % 3 == 0 )
        std::cout << '\n';
}
```

It's basically just a loop to increment i from one to nine and printing each cycle. If the remainder of i/3 is 0, then print a new line char. Also note that it's probably better to just use the logical and expression rather than its macro ( it'll be more readable to most people, the macro only really exists for people that can't easily type `&`).

Comment: I needed a nested loop

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++){ 
   for(int j = 1 ; j <= 3 ; j++)
      cout << i*3 + j << " ";
   cout << endl;}
```

Comment: You need `i < 3`.  Personally, I think the OP's approach of incrementing i in the body is neater.

Comment: yes you are right, I edited my answer

Comment: You *could* explain the answer a bit.

Comment: i is increasing from 0 to 3 so you can think of i as the row number i*3 is the first number in that row.

Comment: then then for every i*3 (the first number in each row) you increase 1,2,3 to be i*3+1, i*3+2 , i*

Comment: 3+ 3 as so on for all values of i